# Get numbers from regex

Tags: java

I receive inputs like IX898 or QX78 ... I create regex

```
String expression="(IX|MX|SX|QX)([0-9]+)";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(expression);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(address);
```

How to find if it matches and if it matches how to get numbers?

Answer (score 6):

```
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to use the group function on Matcher, [here's an example.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/Matchergroupwithparameter.htm)

```
yourMatch.group(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String expression="[a-zA-Z]";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(expression);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(address);
matcher.replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern `\S+?(\d+)` in general.

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(\\S+?(\\d+));
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(string);
if(matcher.matches()){
int num = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you find out if it matches?

```
bool matches = matcher.matches();
```

How do you capture the numbers?

```
if(matches) 
{
    String numbers = matcher.group(2);
    int num = Integer.getInteger(numberString).intVal();
}
```

Read more on [capturing groups](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg) to learn why this works.

Answer (score 0):

[`Matcher.group(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#group%28int%29) should help....

```
    String q = "IX898";
    String expression="(IX|MX|SX|QX)([0-9]+)";
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(expression);
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(q);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
```